# Debugging a cordova android plugin

Tags: android, ios, eclipse, cordova

I have a Cordova project which uses an external plugin. The plugin works fine for iOS; however for Android it is non functional, and requires some debugging. Trying to import it into Eclipse leaves me unable to build the project, thus I can't debug it. I'm running Cordova version 4.3.0.

Is there an easy way to debug the Android code of an external plugin?

Comment: use gabdebug to debug javascript files and eclipse for java codes

Comment: If you are using the latest version of cordova try with android studio instead of eclipse

Comment: Have you checked the "copy files into workapace" option when importing the project? (building fails if you check this option) and have you imported both your app project and the cordovalib project?

Comment: I ended up just upgrading the android platform to the latest version - it fully supports Android Studio integration.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Android's Log class for print out debug messages from your app.

**Example of debugging with the device:**

Insert to your Android code debug lines which you want:

```
Log.d("my_id","My custom string: " + customString);
```

Start debugger on first terminal/shell window:

```
adb logcat -s my_id
```

Start your app on second terminal/shell window:

```
cordova run android --debug --device
```